# Connecting android to a Django server

Tags: android, api

I know that this question is answered several times but i couldn't figure out how should i do this.

How should i send critical information like passwords etc. My Host provider grants SSL certification.

Should i do it with `HttpPost` or it needs to be more secured.

Here is my POST snippet.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://example.com/");
NameValuePair[] data = {
    new NameValuePair("a", "b"),
    new NameValuePair("c", "d")
};
post.setRequestBody(data);
InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the request type (`POST`, `GET`, etc) with the transport method (`HTTP`, `HTTPS`).

If you have been provided with an SSL cert you should set your server up to listen on a secure connection (usually `443` for `HTTPS`, but not necessarily for a server).

Your calls should then be routed to `https://[your_server]/`. They will then be secure.

And really, you should look into using a library for making requests. You are probably going to hit the 'network traffic on the main thread' warning quite soon. Look into 'Fast Android Networking' or 'Volley'.